# Code igniter Cart Class Unable To Store more Then On item

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter `cart class`, when I insert new product to it, overrides existing products below I my code and output please guide me what's wrong with my code.
live test URL is 
           http://outlets.pk/outlets/items_controller/add_to_cart/12/2
           http://outlets.pk/outlets/items_controller/add_to_cart/11/2
           http://outlets.pk/outlets/items_controller/add_to_cart/id/qty

**What I am doing:** 
if we change id then items must be increase in cart.

its properly working on localhost but when I move it on Live hosting it behave unexpectedly.

**Problem:** 
**items_controller/add_to_cart URL is used to add item into cart but when I insert new item into cart and then try to access on other action it returns empty array.**

**SESSIONS** are Not working on shared hosting server.

**This is my functions:**

```
public function add_to_cart($product_id,$qty){
        $result=$this->items_model->get_items_id($product_id);
        $cart_item=$this->items_model->is_exist($this->cart->contents(),$product_id);
        if($cart_item!=NULL){

            $this->cart->update(array(

                'rowid'=> $cart_item['rowid'],
                'qty'=> $cart_item['qty']+$qty,
            ));
        }
        else{
            $this->cart->insert(array(
                'id'=> $result[0]['product_id'],
                'name'=> $result[0]['product_name'],
                'qty'=> $qty,
                'price'=>$result[0]['product_price'],
                'product_sku'=>$result[0]['product_sku']
            ));
        }

        $this->randerCart();


    }
```

**`Is_exist` function code:**

```
public function is_exist($cart_content,$id){
    foreach($cart_content as $c_i){

        if($c_i['id']===$id){

            return $c_i;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us what do you have at function is_exist() at your model

Comment: Please include your code on your `is exists` method from your model.

Comment: is_exist function is now included check it.

Comment: one more thing i have to tell you i have check it now its properly working on localhost but when o move on Live hosting it behave unexpectedly.

Comment: `it behave unexpectedly.` needs more description.. Any errors? What happens? How have you debugged it?

Comment: i have edited my question kindly take a look of it.

Comment: as you say it works on localhost (which has session if I read you right) but it doesn't work on internet host (which does not have session), then it's most likely that you need session on internet host first. Please contact the the third party software project for *cart* and check your support options to find out what the requirements of that third-party-software are and how you can check your installations matching those. Also please restrain for asking third-party-software support questions on Stackoverflow. Keep Stackoverflow for your own codes programming questions.